# Pie Chart - Showing Currency Values - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pie-chart

I think my doubt is simple. I'm trying to create a pie chart from VBA Excel that inform money values. I can only make them appear as raw numbers (not with $, R$ for example).

Here's my code:

```
With grafico_usp
    .Name = "Metrics USP - Quantidade"
    .ChartType = xlPieExploded
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 304
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasLegend = True
    .Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 13
    .Legend.Height = 200
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Estatística Número de Cursos Ofertados - USP"
    .ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowValue)
 End With
```

My cells are also formatted as Currency but the unit doesn't appear in the pie chart.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**It is trivial...**
I just simply recorded a macro and it seems to work for the chart data labels. In the wizard I first added data tables. Then choose to format them under number format by choosing currency.

So in VBA, to achieve the same, you will have to apply number formatting to each of the data series, if you have multiples.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
    .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
End With
```

[image]